How is the current growth or trend of the house church movement?
What is the current growth or statistics of the house church movement in the US, or the West in general? I suppose they don't exist in the UK or Europe. I have heard that this type of church model exists in China and in some poor countries due to an organic need arising from the political situation. However, to see this trend going in the West rich nations is very interesting, where they are moving away from the institutional church model. The house church model also rejects the Pastor system or a senior Pastor system in the structure of church; and they are smaller size to avoid expense of building and maintenance.
Are there some government data that shows surveys of believers to give a good estimate, and how to find it? If you have other basic related information about their structure and whether certain traditional churches have condemned them as heretics, share them as well.

It is a method used by the Orthodox church as well, especially in countries where Christianity is still persecuted or outlawed. A missionary bishop I personally know as a friend referred to it as "Church in a box", because they could setup in different buildings. Ultimately things like the altar are simply a table, the Iconostasis wall can be as modest as a few icons, ... this is of course due to a political need and is not a sign of moving away from an institutional model. It does not reject a priesthood. They are generally designed to avoid detection, it will be difficult to find info.

Those would be just a smaller scale version of the traditional hierarchical structure; whereas the house churches are the independent next step of evolution in the evangelical sector.

It is weird to me, to cast away all guard rails and attempt to bowl a perfect strike of salvation.

Such gatherings are, in their very nature, not documented. It is going to be difficult to quantify. I attended such a 'house meeting' in the late 1960s in the West London area. But it was led by, very much, a 'Minister' in every sense of that word. It was a serious attempt to leave denominationalism. (And it is still thriving.)

House churches absolutely exist in Europe. There's enough variety in Christianity that anywhere there's a large number of Christians, some are almost certainly going to come to a model like this. I have no idea how widespread though, and I don't see how it could possibly be measured.
